# how can i select the 2nd row from every group from MySQL

Tags: mysql

How can i select the 2nd row from every group from MySQL like as below fig.

[image]

Comment: After order by put `LIMIT 1,1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following Query in MySQL:

SELECT C.groupname,C.marks FROM querysecondval C LEFT JOIN ( SELECT A.groupid,IFNULL(B.groupid,0) groupid2 FROM querysecondval 
A LEFT JOIN ( SELECT B.groupid FROM querysecondval B GROUP BY B.groupname order by B.groupid ) B ON A.groupid = B.groupid 
) D ON C.groupid = D.groupid WHERE D.groupid2=0 GROUP BY C.groupname  order by C.groupid

Comment: Thank you so much dheeraj :)